# Detectar aumento de jTable.lenght en java swing

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un formulario con un jTable y me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para tener como un bucle infinito que detecte si aumento el numero de filas de mi jtable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo quisiera saber como detectar si se aumento el numero de filas de mi jtable a cada rato o cada 3 segundos

y bueno para hacerlo que a cada segundo detecte y no se detenga o se crashee lo pondria en un hilo y dentro del hilo hago un while true creo y el hilo lo correria en el evento opened de mi formulario

porque lo que deseo hacer es que cada vez que se detecte que aumento la fila de mi jtable, aparezca una ventana popup como.

lo de que aparezca la ventana y se deslice como una notificacion de el antiguo messenger ya lo tengo, solo me faltaria tener una funcion que detecte el aumento de mis filas de mi jtable

Comment: No creo en la necesidad de un `Thread`, sugeriría mucho mejor (y para eso está) usar un listener en el modelo de la tabla. De ese modo cada que haya un cambio en dicho modelo, en este caso de una nueva fila, se dispararía el PopUp. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningforChangestotheRowsandColumnsofaJTableComponent.htm

Comment: te refieres al evento listener del jtable? no entiendo :( y el ejmeplo que me mandaste el link tampoco :c